# In the given sentence, should I mix the tenses, or should I keep them in harmony?

Tags: past-tense, subject-verb-agreement, parallelism

> I thought you were one of those people who didn't like dogs.
>
> I thought you were one of those people who don't like dogs.

Are both the above sentences grammatically correct?
Is there a difference in their meaning?

Comment: I don't find "don't" to be natural at all. I'd phrase it using "doesn't", not "don't".

Answer (score 1):

Break the sentence down:

> I'm one of those people who don't like dogs.
>
> I thought you were one of those people who don't like dogs.

Also, note that there are cases where the past tense is correct:

> I thought you were one of those people who missed last month's meeting.